# How to Return a vector to Windows thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, vector

I have written a library which comprises of function and two thread functions. From the user program I will call the function inside the library with Drive id as parameter. The function creates threads according to no of Drive Id I have given. Then this thread function will process the drive getting list of folders from the drive and put it in a queue. Once it finishes it will call certain amount of threads (which i initialized with MAX_Threads) and these child threads will process the queue and put list of files inside the drive in their corresponding vector. Now my problem is I have to return these vector to the statement which called the library. I referred through many sites but i didn't got the intended result.

The snippet which I implemented is..

```
ListFiles(string DriveId)
{
    loop(no of drives)
        create Threads
}
DWORD WINAPI FileList::ParThread(LPVOID s)
{
    //Process Drive
    directories.push_back(path + "\\" + ffd.cFileName); //global queue 
    //it will be locked and then inserted and released by each thread

    loop(Max - threads)
        CreateThreads
}
DWORD WINAPI FileList::List(LPVOID s)
{
    //create vector local to each thread
    //create local queue that copies values from global queue and processing occurs in local queue
    //inserts file name into vector

}
```

Now I want to return these vectors to the statement which called the function ListFiles which is in library.

Comment: How about a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with the thread-id as key and the vector as data? Then when all threads are done, just collect all vectors in the map into a single vector.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg..Thanks for the idea..but rather than that i would go for a double vector,or instead a global vector in my program.Please provide any snippet or code that returns the vector to the function that calls it according to my program...

Comment: You need a `callback` mechanism when the vectors full or populated, this callback procedure will do that you need. Returning vector from `ListFiles` function break the logic related to multitheading

Comment: If you have a single "global" vector, you need to protect it with semaphores or the like, or you will have chaos when multiple threads try to manipulate the vector. A vector of vectors may work, if you push the inner vector before starting each thread, and pass the index to that vector to the thread. You still have to collate the vectors afterwards though.

Comment: @FredrickGauss...Now tats something interesting.how to implement that mechanism in my code ? Please provide any alteration in my code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg..If i go with Global vector with proper locking by threads then will that locking by threads increases execution time..i mean would it affect the performance of the program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library function can create the vector and pass its address in the LPVOID thread parameter. If you need multiple vectors put them all in a struct and pass the address of the struct in the LPVOID thread parameter.

Comment: you are telling about passing the vectors to threads.Am asking how to return it to the calling statement from the threads that processes it.

Comment: If you  pass a pointer to a vector to a thread then when the thread has ended you have the updated vector. This has the same effect as returning a vector.

Comment: @ScottMc...Now i understood something from your point.U r saying send vector as parameter to thread and get it as a out parameter right.Can u please express ur idea by any code ....?